# Forcing refresh/reload of url in one browser when url in second browser window is updated

Tags: python, django

I have a website written using django that has text entry, voting, and a table display of the entries sorted by age and votes, all on one page:
http://www.highscore.a2hosted.com/index/

Now I would like to have separate entry, voting, and table pages, and I have started with the voting page. This works well, and votes are added to entries in the underlying sqlite3 database, but I have to refresh the table page (index) manually.

Is there an easy way to force update, or at a last resort, reload of the table data in the table (index) url from actions in the voting url or views.py?

I include code snippets below:

**views.py**

```
def index(request):   
  context = {
   'latest_entry_list': Entry.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:10],
   'high_entry_list': Entry.objects.order_by('-score','-pub_date')[:10],
   'high_entry': Entry.objects.order_by('-score','-pub_date')[:1],
   'low_entry_list': Entry.objects.order_by('score','-pub_date')[:10],
   'voting_entry_list': Entry.objects.unvoted_or_random(),
  }
  return render(request, 'entries/index.html', context);

def voteup(request):
  voting_id = request.GET.get('voteid')
  if request.method=='GET':
    v = Entry.objects.get(pk=voting_id)
    v.score +=1
    v.voted=True
    v.save()
  else:
    pass
  return HttpResponse('done')
```

**voting.html**

```
 <div id="Vote" class = "high">
<div style="text-align: center">
  {% for entry in voting_entry_list %} 
    <li><a href="/entries/{{ entry.id }}/">{{ entry.text }}&nbsp{{ entry.score }}</a></li>
    <p>
    <input type="submit" id="voteid" name='voteid' value="{{ entry.id }}" autofocus value="" onfocus="this.value = this.value;" class = "transparent"/>
          <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
              $("#voteid").bind("keydown", function(e) { //input type=id above
                if (e.keyCode == 38) {
                  var text = $("#voteid").val();        
                  var args = {'voteid':text};       
                  $.get("/voteup/", args).done(function(data) {
                    console.log("message: " + data);
                    location.reload();
                  });
                return false;
                }       
               });
             });        
          </script>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

---

**EDIT for code based on accepted answer;**

Thanks, I took your first option and I did this on the tables page:

```
 <script>
  setTimeout(function() {
  $.ajax({      
    url: "",
    context: document.body,
    success: function(s,x){
        $(this).html(s);
    }
   });
  }, 1000);
 </script>
```

Comment: I removed the database and the [tag:url] tag, because your question is a bit more generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an easy way to force update, or at a last resort, reload of
>   the table data in the table (index) url from actions in the voting url
>   or views.py?

What you are looking for is a way to let the browser automatically check for updates from the back end, and then update itself without "refreshing".

It is similar to how notifications work on StackOverflow. If you get a new message or a change in your reputation, the top bar updates itself without you having to refresh.

To accomplish this, you have two options:

1. You can poll the database every *x* seconds from your front end, and then trigger an update. This is basically an automated way to hit "F5".
2. You can open a socket so that your front end is updated when the backend is updated.

Either way will require you to add some front end logic. For option #2, you can use [`django-socketio`](http://django-socketio.readthedocs.org/en/latest) an app that uses the [socket.io](http://socket.io) library to implement the [`WebSocket` protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) which is a way to open *sockets* (think of it like a permanent connection), between the browser and the backend.

On the back end you would create a channel, on which you would transmit messages. The browser will subscribe to these channels and listen. As soon as the message is transmitted from your backend, the browser can trigger an update (for example, add a new row to a table, popup a warning, etc.)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was hoping to avoid, but you've made the choices nice and clear, thank you very much!

Comment: I have edited my question to include code based on your first option, and have accepted your answer for putting me on the right track

Answer (score 1):

try to do this :

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def voteup(request):
    voting_id = request.GET.get('voteid')
    if request.method=='GET':
        v = Entry.objects.get(pk=voting_id)
        v.score +=1
        v.voted=True
        v.save()
        return redirect(reverse('index'))
    #redirect to you index and refrech the data

    else:
       pass
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I just get an error as below

GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/voteup/?voteid=20 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR) jquery.min.js:4
send jquery.min.js:4
n.extend.ajax jquery.min.js:4
n.(anonymous function) jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous function) (index):56
n.event.dispatch jquery.min.js:3
r.handle

But even if it worked, wouldn't it just send me to the index?
I would like to have the index in another browser window update, while remaining in the voting browser window. Sorry if that was unclear